# How to sort the string in a list in descending and extract largest string number from it

Tags: java, list, sorting

Below is my list which will always be in the form of `aXXXX` -

```
List<String> child = Arrays.asList("a5", "a10", "a2", "a1", "a40");
System.out.println(child);
```

My `child` list will always have strings in the form of `aXXXX`

Now I need to sort my above lists and extract the largest string from it..

So in the above example, it will be `a40`. I was initially thinking to use `Collections.sort(child);` but it's not sorting them out in the ascending order properly.

Comment: What is your Expected output ?

Comment: Well, this is expected, isn't it? Is it only ever `a` as a prefix for your strings or can it be anything else?

Comment: use comparable interface to sort

Comment: If you have all the item prefix of 'a' then sort the number and show 'a' when display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Comparator which defines the sorting strategie:
See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static final Comparator<String> aStringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            //assumed input are strings in the form axxxx
            int numfromS1 = Integer.valueOf(s1.subSequence(1, s1.length()).toString());
            int numfromS2 = Integer.valueOf(s2.subSequence(1, s2.length()).toString());
            return numfromS1 - numfromS2;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> child = Arrays.asList("a5", "a10", "a2", "a1", "a40");
        Collections.sort(child, aStringComparator);
        System.out.println(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. One last thing, currently it is sorting out in ascending order.. How would I sort this out in descending order?

Comment: I think you can make this for yourself if you adapt the compare method a little bit ;)

Comment: Sure. But I am facing some problem in doing that as well. I have never wrote comparator before so having some issues with that.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorting will be possible, but you have to extract the "a" at the beginning and treat the rest as an integer number to prevent the string `"2"` from being bigger then the string `"10"`. Try  a `Comparator` doing this, or create a new list containing only extracted integers.

Answer (score 0):

You was almost there. The possible solution is to write your own comparator:

```
Collections.sort(child,new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        \\compare 2 values
        return result;
    }
});
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Possible values to return:

```
-1 : lhs < rhs
0 : lhs == rhs
+1 : lhs > rhs
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already shown how to do this with Java 7.

This could also be done with the following using Java 8:

```
    List<String> child = Arrays.asList("a5", "a10", "a2", "a1", "a40");
    String result = child.stream()
            .sorted(
                    Collections.reverseOrder(
                            Comparator.comparing(
                                    c -> Integer.parseInt(c.substring(1, c.length()))
                            )
                    )
            )
            .findFirst().get();
    System.out.println(result);
```

What this does is:

1. Obtain a `Stream<String>` from your `child`.
2. Create a reversed `Comparator<String>`, which compares based on the lambda `c -> Integer.parseInt(c.substring(1, c.length()))`, which parses the text from the second character onwards as a string.
3. Finds the first result.
4. Gets it out of the `Optional<String>` that `findFirst()` returns, with `get()`.

The `Comparator` could be written more nicely by appending `.reversed()` to it instead of wrapping it in `Collections.reverseOrder()`, but I am unsure how it works as of now.